# Handler of AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException doesn't get called in production

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio-2015, .net-4.6

The situation is following. Crystal Reports have some problems with .net-4.6 and throw an exception (`System.IO.FileNotFoundException` while trying to load a `crdb_adoplus.dll`) with call stack starting at `CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.DataSetConversion.DataSetConverter.DataSetProcessingDelegate` -- which means, I can't wrap it in a try-catch-block. To at least log such Problems, there is an `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException`-handler set as the very first action in my `Sub Main`. And it is working, but **only** if I run the application from Visual Studio, and it **doesn't work** if the app is run directly.

P.S. I know how to make the Crystal Reports work (`useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy`), I'm only looking for a way to process such errors.

**Update1**: It's Windows Forms Application and **both handlers** for `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException` and `Application.ThreadException` **are working** (latter with `Application.SetUnhandledExceptionMode(UnhandledExceptionMode.CatchException, True)`), but this special exception for some reason doesn't (but only if not started from Visual Studio...)

The `Sub Main` looks like following.

```
<STAThread()>
Sub Main()
    AddHandler AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException, AddressOf UnhandledThreadExceptionHandler
    Application.SetUnhandledExceptionMode(UnhandledExceptionMode.CatchException, True)

    'many lines of code...

    AddHandler Application.ThreadException, AddressOf ThreadExceptionHandler
    Application.Run(x)
End Sub
```

Update1.1: (forgot the handler)

```
Private wsExNr As Integer = 0

Friend Sub UnhandledThreadExceptionHandler(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As UnhandledExceptionEventArgs)
    Dim ex = TryCast(e.ExceptionObject, Exception)

    If ex IsNot Nothing Then
        ex.Data.Add("isUnhandledThreadExceptionHandler", True)
        ex.Data.Add("isMainThread", (Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId = wsMainThreadId))
        If sender IsNot Nothing Then
            ex.Data.Add("Sender", sender.GetType.FullName)
        End If
    End If

    Dim path = IO.Path.Combine(My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Desktop, "Exception_Log")
    IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(path) 'no need in checking if it exists etc -- it's built-in.

    Dim nr = Threading.Interlocked.Increment(wsExNr)
    Dim timestamp_str = ""
    Try
        timestamp_str = Now.ToString("yyyyMMddhhmmss.fff")
    Catch : End Try
    Using wr As New IO.StreamWriter(IO.Path.Combine(path, "ex" & timestamp_str & "_" & nr & ".txt"))
        wr.WriteLine("UnhandledThreadExceptionHandler!")
        If ex IsNot Nothing Then
            wr.WriteLine(ex.ToString)
        End If
    End Using

    If ex IsNot Nothing Then
        If Core.Visual.Dialogs.Internal.MainWindow IsNot Nothing AndAlso Core.Visual.Dialogs.Internal.MainWindow.IsHandleCreated Then
            Core.Visual.Dialogs.Internal.MainWindow.Invoke(New Action(Of Exception)(AddressOf ShowUnhandledThreadException), ex)
        Else
            MsgBox("UnhandledException:" & vbNewLine & ex.ToString)
        End If
    Else
        MsgBox("UnhandledException:" & vbNewLine & e.ExceptionObject.ToString)
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub ShowUnhandledThreadException(ByVal ex As Exception)
    'this is basically a MsgBox
    Core.Visual.Dialogs.ExceptionDialog.Show(
        ex,
        Diagnostics.EventLogEntryType.Error,
        True)
End Sub
```

Comment: Is this a WPF or Windows Forms application?

Comment: Could you show us how you subscribe to the event, and what you do in it? -- Also, have you tried setting the exception mode: `Application.SetUnhandledExceptionMode(UnhandledExceptionMode.CatchException);`?

Comment: @visual-vincent see Update1

Comment: @alexw it's Windows Forms (also see Update1)

Comment: `'many lines of code...` is the problem.  This exception will be raised when Crystal is loaded.  Triggered by the just-in-time compiler.  Which needs to compile Main() before it can start running.  So the exception is raised *before* it gets to your AddHandler statement.  You need to write another method and move the risky code into it.  Technically you should give it the [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Noinlining)] attribute but that isn't necessary when it is this large.

Comment: @HansPassant the application is running without problems, until I press a "Print Report" button somewhere else (it's even a separate .dll), I think `Main` is fine (it also wouldn't explain why does it work properly -- handler is triggered -- when started from Visual Studio)